# External List from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, bcs

I want to know can we create an external list for SharePoint Online from SharePoint 2010 list as a source. ?

Answer (score 2):

BCS in SP Online can only connect to Azure and OData sources, so if you can synchronize the list to one of those I suppose you could connect to it that way.

Possibly a better way to do this would be to store the data in another database and connect to it as an external list in both environments.